# php preg_match_all kills page for unknown reason

Tags: php, email, preg-match-all

I am trying to validate a bunch of text and check if there are any emails in it... so i use the following code:

```
if (preg_match_all("/^([a-zA-Z0-9_.-])+@([a-zA-Z0-9_.-])+\\.([a-zA-Z])+([a-zA-Z])+/", $str, $matches)){

}
```

this will work for TEXT_A in Page1

but when i go in Page2 and try to check again on TEXT_A it will kill the page with "Problem loading page" error...

if i remove this check the page will load fine... i dont get why this is happening...

edit:im using CodeIgniter

Comment: Do you have error reporting on?

Comment: the page stops loading with errors: "The connection was reset
      
      
      
      
      
        
        
          The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading."(not php errors but browser errors)

Comment: Do you have PHP's error reporting turned on? (using `error_reporting()`, if not, turn it on using `error_reporting(E_ALL);`)

Comment: Note that critical PHP errors are also logged to the web server's log. Look in /var/log/apache2/error.log.

Comment: So you have the same check in page1 and page2, but only page2 crashes. Then the problem is clearly elsewhere in page2's code. If I'm not understanding this correctly, let me know :)

Comment: @Roadmaster nothing weird going on there...
#Pekka im using CI so i have set error logging to error messages

Comment: @Roadmaster thats what im suspecting as well... weird is that i dont see anything wrong in it... propably will check it tomorrow again line by line

Comment: BTW, the php 5.3 function filter_var() does a great job validating emails: filter_var('bob@example.com', FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL), this might fix your bug if it's related to your regex.

Comment: @Mathieu im talking about a bunch of data which can have plenty of emails,urls...

Answer (score 1):

I see a problem in your regex that could cause [Catastrophic Backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html).

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9_.-])+@([a-zA-Z0-9_.-])+\\.([a-zA-Z])+([a-zA-Z])+
                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

What do you want to match in the area I marked?

How should the regex know from which letter on the second group should apply?

If you have a longer sequence of letters that can match, the regex will need a lot of steps to match that **==> you have a performance problem, the regex just don't finish in time!**

I would say you can just remove the last group and the regex will match the same, but much faster.

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9_.-])+@([a-zA-Z0-9_.-])+\\.([a-zA-Z])+
```